# What shell feature did surprise you?

Tags: shell, posix

So I thought I was an old fart who knew his **Bourne/POSIX shell** inside out. Still, sometimes I am surprised when I learn of a new feature. Even happens after 25 years. Examples:

Optional open parens for patterns in `case` statements:

```
case $foo in
    (bar) foobar;;
    (baz) foobaz;;
esac
```

Makes my `vi` % motion command happy as the parentheses are now symmetric!

Redirection can appear anywhere in a simple command, not just after the last arg:

```
>ls.out ls
>wc.out wc <.profile -l
```

This can be used to make long pipes look more "natural" as in

```
<infile cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 >outfile
```

There can be more than one here-document (even for the same fd):

```
cat <<EOF1 <<EOF2
  foo
EOF1
  bar
EOF2
```

Please restrict your answers to plain Bourne and POSIX shells (no bash or zsh specific features, thanks!).

Comment: Amazing. My question got shot down within 60 seconds flat :-) While I thought it *does* have a lot to do with programming, I realize "surprises" have certainly a subjective nature. Anyone interested in this may follow the thread of the same name in comp.unix.shell, started after my misguided attempt at karma-collection. No hard feelings, but keep the up-votes coming... :-)